# Why does this function return NaN?

Tags: javascript

```
function getNucleobaseCount (strand) {
  /*
  Returns occurences of nucleobases A and C respectively
  */
  var countA = (strand.split("A").lenght - 1);
  var countC = (strand.split("C").lenght - 1);
  return countA + " " + countC;
}
```

But

```
> console.log(getNucleobaseCount("AAGCATT"))
Nan Nan
```

Instead of the expected `3 1`

Why?

Comment: `lenght` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: Why don't you perform some basic troubleshooting, and log the various values you're using in the `getNucleobaseCount()` function? You shouldn't need to ask for help to solve such a simple problem.

Comment: @user2736012 See my comment under Quentin's answer why I didn't expect a misspelled word to be the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spelling mistake

Comment: @Bentley4: That doesn't make any difference. Unless you genuinely think that JavaScript is incapable of performing basic arithmetic, then it should be clear that there's something wrong with the data. So the next step would be to perform basic debugging steps, like logging the values that are being operated on.

Comment: ...if your entire debugging process is to look for an error message to tell you what's wrong, then ask StackOverflow to tell you what's wrong, you're missing a really big step.

Comment: @user2736012 I'm not claiming that I couldn't have found it fairly easily(I said: "Can't believe I looked over that".) . It's just that if I would have never programmed in Python I'm convinced I would have spotted it quite fast. I guess I just wasn't really focused.
Also, my statement didn't imply that if in Python the Error was not named `NameError` I wouldn't be able to easily find such a mistake. I just know it's classified as a NameError, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: You're missing the point. It's not that you made the mistake, or weren't able to visually spot it. It's that problems like this are easily solved with a minimal amount of basic analysis and deductive reasoning. That's the important part that appears to have been left out of your process.

Comment: I did say "I guess I wasn't really focused". Increasing focus increases the rigor of your perceptions and deductions. Almost every (or every?) question on S.O. can be avoided by focusing more. There are just different degrees of focus needed for solving different problems. You've made clear to where the lowest limit of degree of focus is for you to be appropriate to post on S.O. . However, this border is arbitrary. There will always be cases which you disapprove. Isn't it a better system for everyone to only post answers to questions they deem worthy formulating an answer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `lenght` property will be `undefined`.

`undefined - 1` is `NaN`

You misspelt `length`.

Comment: Can't believe I looked over that. However I'm used to writing in Python so my expectation for a mispelled method was to get something similar to a NameError.

Answer (score 1):

Misspelling of `length`? I would think that it would show a compilation error though.

Comment: JavaScript isn't a compiled language.

Comment: ahh yes... that would make sense.

Answer (score -2):

you have 
misspelled 'length' :-)

```
function getNucleobaseCount (strand) {
  /*
  Returns occurences of nucleobases A and C respectively
  */
  var countA = (strand.split("A").length - 1);
  var countC = (strand.split("C").length - 1);
  return countA + " " + countC;
}
```

Comment: This was established more than 20 mins previously to your answer.